# sign in with apple in Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I want to sign in with apple in my Apple Watch .after I write those codes below ,start to run the code.It show me a view with label showed that AUTH ALERT SIGN_IN NOT COMPLETED

```
 ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider *provider = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider new];
 ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest *request = [provider createRequest];
   request.requestedScopes = @[ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,ASAuthorizationScopeEmail];
    ASAuthorizationController *controller =  [[ASAuthorizationController alloc]initWithAuthorizationRequests:@[request]];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller performRequests];
```

Comment: Please file a bug report for this using  https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome. Make sure to download the appropriate profile to retrieve a sysdiagnose for the watch.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Capability "Sign in With Apple" under Signing and Capabilities in your Watch Extension target.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `WatchApp Extension` Project Settings. There you can add the project capability.

Also you must go to `developer.apple.com` to create and download a `.p8` file. Make sure to save this somewhere as you cannot download it again.